# Tree structure using JSON PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

Hi all i tried working on tree structure using JSON in php,So i am getting values in array when i print array  and it is coming values as perfect but  when i try to convert to JSON its not showing any pages.

Here is my fetching data:(fetch.php)

```
<?php 
include ("../include/session.php");
global $database;
$simid = isset($_POST['simid']) ? $_POST['simid'] : 11;
$query = "SELECT 
t1.id AS g_menu_id, t1.ref_page_id AS g_parent_id, t1.description AS grandParent, 
t2.id AS p_menu_id, t2.ref_page_id AS p_parent_id, t2.description AS parent, 
t3.id AS c_menu_id, t3.ref_page_id AS c_parent_id, t3.description AS children 
FROM simulationpages t1 
LEFT JOIN simulationpages t2 ON t2.ref_page_id = t1.id 
left JOIN simulationpages t3 ON t3.ref_page_id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.ref_page_id = 0 AND t1.simid='".$simid."' AND t1.status=1
ORDER BY t1.pagelevel,t2.pagelevel,t3.pagelevel"; 

$result = $database->query($query); 
$data = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
if(!array_key_exists($row['g_menu_id'], $data)) 
{ 
$temp = array(); 
$temp['menu_id'] = $row['g_menu_id']; 
$temp['text'] = $row['grandParent']; 
$temp['parent_id'] = $row['g_parent_id']; 

if( trim($row['parent']) != '' ) 
{ 
$parent = array(); 
$parent['menu_id'] = $row['p_menu_id']; 
$parent['text'] = $row['parent']; 
$parent['parent_id'] = $row['p_parent_id']; 
if( trim($row['children']) != '' ) 
{ 
$childrenData = array(); 
$childrenData['menu_id'] = $row['c_menu_id']; 
$childrenData['text'] = $row['children']; 
$childrenData['parent_id'] = $row['c_parent_id']; 
$parent['nodes'][ $childrenData['menu_id'] ] = $childrenData; 
} 
$temp['nodes'][ $parent['menu_id'] ] = $parent; 
} 

$data[ $row['g_menu_id'] ] = $temp; 
} 
else 
{ 
if(! array_key_exists($row['p_menu_id'], $data[ $row['g_menu_id'] ]['nodes'] )) 
{ 
$parent = array(); 
$parent['menu_id'] = $row['p_menu_id']; 
$parent['text'] = $row['parent']; 
$parent['parent_id'] = $row['p_parent_id']; 
if( trim($row['children']) != '' ) 
{ 
$childrenData = array(); 
$childrenData['menu_id'] = $row['c_menu_id']; 
$childrenData['text'] = $row['children']; 
$childrenData['parent_id'] = $row['c_parent_id']; 
$parent['nodes'][ $childrenData['menu_id'] ] = $childrenData; 
} 

$data[ $row['g_menu_id'] ]['nodes'][ $row['p_menu_id'] ] = $parent; 
} 
else 
{ 
if( trim($row['children']) != '' ) 
{ 
$childrenData = array(); 
$childrenData['menu_id'] = $row['c_menu_id']; 
$childrenData['text'] = $row['children']; 
$childrenData['parent_id'] = $row['c_parent_id']; 
$data[ $row['g_menu_id'] ]['nodes'][ $row['p_menu_id'] ]['nodes'][ $childrenData['menu_id'] ] = $childrenData; 
} 
} 
} 
} 

//echo "<pre>"; 
//print_r($data);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and we followed up these tutorial.

[`http://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/make-treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-ajax-jquery-with-php.html`](http://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/make-treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-ajax-jquery-with-php.html)

And here is the ajax code which we used for fetching the data :

```
              $.ajax({
                url: "fetch.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: ({simid: <?php echo $simid;?>}),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {

 $('#treeview').treeview({
                        data: data,
                        onNodeSelected: function (event, data) {
                            var m1 = JSON.stringify(data, ['menu_id']);
                            var m2 = jQuery.parseJSON(m1);

                            var s1 = JSON.stringify(data, ['sim_id']);
                            var s2 = jQuery.parseJSON(s1);

                                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'content.php?type=tree&nextpageid='+m2.menu_id,

                    success: function() {

                        $('#myContent').html('<iframe src="content.php?type=tree&nextpageid='+m2.menu_id+'" id="winId" style="width:105%;height:550px;border-width: 0px;"></iframe>');

                    }
               });

                        }

                    });
                }
            });
```

Here is the array result which i am getting:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 1
            [text] => Welcome Page
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 2
            [text] => Grand Parent
            [parent_id] => 0
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_id] => 5
                            [text] => Parent page 2
                            [parent_id] => 2
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_id] => 3
                            [text] => Parent page 1
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [menu_id] => 4
                                            [text] => Children page 1
                                            [parent_id] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And i am getting error in console like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeId' of undefined bootstrap-treeview.min.js:1**

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue, I tried a lot to fix that but i couldn't able to find where is the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Indent your code properly. That will make it easier for both you and us to read it and to follow the flow. 2. You need to show us the json you're getting. We can't guess what result your code produces.

Comment: ok i will add json result.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i added result which i am getting can you please check